# Gmail API iOS in Xcode 7, Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7, gmail-api

I am following Google's tutorial https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift to create a simple Swift project but compiler throws below error. Is this due to some changes in Xcode 7,Swift 2 ? Any idea how to fix it

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLService", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceGmail in GTLGmail_Sources.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceGmail)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for ObjectiveC.GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailDraft in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailHistory in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryLabelAdded in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryLabelRemoved in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryMessageAdded in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryMessageDeleted in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGmailLabel in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQuery", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryGmail in GTLGmail_Sources.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryGmail)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLService", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceGmail in GTLGmail_Sources.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceGmail)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQuery", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryGmail in GTLGmail_Sources.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryGmail)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailDraft in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryLabelAdded in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryLabelRemoved in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailMessage in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryMessageAdded in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailHistoryMessageDeleted in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGmailHistory in GTLGmail_Sources.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: just received and answer from gmail api forum saying the new version of sdk solves the issue. havn't tried it yet.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857833/quick-start-instructions-for-gmail-api-on-xcode-7-do-not-work/34969420#34969420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Gmail API to latest version fixes this issue.